# Mysql Add days onto date from two different columns

Tags: mysql, mamp, dateadd

Hi my problem relates to adding days onto a date from two different tables in MySql in the Mamp environment.

[image: Membership transaction]
[image: Membership type]
Membership type to Membership transaction is 1 to many
The link is `type_id`

Date is in `yyyy/mm/dd` format also as this is the only format that Mamp will allow from my research.
I want a new end date column that links to the column duration from the membership type table. I want to add `Duration_day` onto `start_date` to produce an end date that matches up with the type_id. (So they link up to give the correct end date)
I want it to be automatically calculated when the start date and type-id are saved

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far and what is not working

Comment: Edit your original question. Please use text like `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` to show the structure of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a trigger on INSERT/UPDATE - a calculated column (for MySQL v5.7.6+) will not work in your case (it can only refer to columns in the same table).
The 2 triggers may look like this

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%' TRIGGER `m_duration_ins_tr1` BEFORE INSERT ON `membership`
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE duration INTEGER;
    SELECT m_duration INTO duration FROM membership_type WHERE id = NEW.type_id;
    SET NEW.end_date := DATE_ADD(NEW.start_date, INTERVAL duration DAY);
END;

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%' TRIGGER `m_duration_ins_tr1` BEFORE UPDATE ON `membership`
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE duration INTEGER;
    SELECT m_duration INTO duration FROM membership_type WHERE id = NEW.type_id;
    SET NEW.end_date := DATE_ADD(NEW.start_date, INTERVAL duration DAY);
END;
```